# SELECT 1 FROM JOIN with complex conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables with a one-to-many relationship, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE samples (                                                
     id BIGSERIAL,                                                                            
     name character varying(250)  NOT NULL,                                   
     create_date timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NOW(),                           
     PRIMARY KEY (id),
);

CREATE TABLE sample_compounds (                                       
     id BIGSERIAL,
     sample_id integer ,                                                               
     compound_name character varying(250)  NULL,                              
     is_mixture_analysis boolean NULL,                                       
     score double precision  NULL,                                            
     PRIMARY KEY (id),                                                        
     CONSTRAINT sample_compounds_sample_id_fkey                                   
        FOREIGN KEY (sample_id) 
        REFERENCES samples(id)
);
```

I need to join the two tables and select one row from sample_compounds based on certain conditions.  In pseudo SQL, I'd imagine it would be something like this, but the multiple conditions has me confused about where to start.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.create_date, sc.compound_name
FROM samples s
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT id, sample_id, compound_name, score, is_mixture_analysis
  FROM sample_compounds
  WHERE 
   condition1 
   OR condition2 
   OR condition3 
  LIMIT 1
) sc ON sc.sample_id=s.id
```

Here are the conditions I need to have...

**Condition 1**: If is_mixture_analysis has true values only, select the one with the highest score. For example, if the joining data from sample_compounds looked like this:

```
                   compound_name                    | score | is_mixture_analysis 
----------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------
 Soluble Starch                                     |    97 | t
 Starch                                             |    96 | t
 Illite, Morris IL,                                 |    95 | t
 Acacia gum                                         |    94 | t
 Attapalgite, crude, Attapalgus, GA                 |    62 | t
```

The answer should be: *Soluble Starch*.

**Condition 2**: If is_mixture_analysis has false values only, select the one with the highest score. For example, if the joining data from sample_compounds looked like this:

```
              compound_name               | score | is_mixture_analysis 
------------------------------------------+-------+---------------------
 Nail Polish Remover (Methyl Acetate)     |    96 | f
 4-Styrenesulfonic acid                   |    95 | f
 Dowex                                    |    94 | f
 1,6-bis-(p-Methyl phenyl)-1,6-hexanediol |    94 | f
```

The answer should be: *Nail Polish Remover (Methyl Acetate)*.

**Condition 3**: If is_mixture_analysis has both true and false values, select the row with the highest score where is_mixture_analsis is false but only if it has a score >= 95, else select the row with the highest score where is_mixture_analysis is true. For example, if the joining data from sample_compounds looked like this:

```
            compound_name             | score | is_mixture_analysis 
--------------------------------------+-------+---------------------
 Adenosine triphosphate disodium salt |    98 | f
 Stannous sulfate                     |    97 | f
 Vanadyl sulfate                      |    96 | f
 Cerium IV sulfate                    |   100 | t
```

The answer should be: *Adenosine triphosphate disodium salt*.

But, if the data looked like this:

```
            compound_name             | score | is_mixture_analysis 
--------------------------------------+-------+---------------------
 Adenosine triphosphate disodium salt |    94 | f
 Stannous sulfate                     |    93 | f
 Vanadyl sulfate                      |    92 | f
 Cerium IV sulfate                    |   100 | t
 Cerium sulfate                       |   99  | t
```

The answer should be: *Cerium IV sulfate*.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, @a_horse_with_no_name.  I cleaned up my question by removing the dash and the concat symbols.  To be clear, my question outlines 3 different criteria (conditions).  I'm not trying to concatenate them but, instead, I'm trying to use one condition based based the sample_compound data being joined.  If is_mixture_analysis is all true in the sample_compounds data, then I need to use criteria1; if is_mixture_analysis is all false, then use criteria2; if is_mixture_analysis is both true and false, then use criteria3.  Does that make sense?

Comment: so you have multiple compounds per sample id and you want to select 1 per sampleid with applied conditions ? is that correct?

Comment: @eshirvana yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do it using window functions

```
select s.id, s.name, s.create_date, sc.compound_name, sc.score
from samples s
join sample_compounds sc
on s.id = sc.sample_id 
join ( select
         sample_id
         ,is_mixture_analysis
         ,max(score) score 
         ,row_number() over (partition by sample_id order by case when is_mixture_analysis= false and max(score) >= 95 then 1 else 0 end desc) rn 
       from sample_compounds
       group by sample_id ,is_mixture_analysis
) t
 on t.sample_id = sc.sample_id 
 and t.is_mixture_analysis = sc.is_mixture_analysis
 and t.score = sc.score
 and t.rn =1 ;
```

so basically I'm grouping by sample_id ,is_mixture_analysis to find out the max score but also using row_number() to check if there are both true/false in is_mixture_analysis in a sample , to sort based on the score >= 95 and is_mixture_analysis = false.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish this is to use CTEs to get a count of all possible samples, a count of those with true values, and a count of those with false values and then for your criteria see if the couts match up:

```sql
WITH
-- count of total sample compounds per sample
numentries AS
(SELECT sample_id , count(id) c
FROM sample_compounds
WHERE is_mixture_analysis = true
GROUP BY sample_id), 
-- count of true sample compounds per sample
numtrue AS
(SELECT sample_id , count(id) c
FROM sample_compounds
WHERE is_mixture_analysis = true
GROUP BY sample_id),
-- count of false sample compounds per sample
numfalse AS
(SELECT sample_id , count(id) c
FROM sample_compounds
WHERE is_mixture_analysis = false
GROUP BY sample_id)
--core query
SELECT s.id, s.name, s.create_date, sc.compound_name
FROM samples s
 LEFT OUTER JOIN numentries ne ON (s.sample_id = ne.sample_id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN numtrue nt ON (s.sample_id = ne.sample_id)
 LEFT OUTER JOIN numfalse nf ON (s.sample_id = ne.sample_id),
sample_compounds sc
  WHERE sc.sample_id=s.id
  AND (
   --contiditon 1 - all true
   (ne.c = nt.c)  
   --condition 2 - all false
   OR ((ne.c <> nt.c) AND (nf.c = nt.c) )
   --condition 3 - mix of true and false and score greater than 95
   OR ((ne.c <> nt.c) AND (nf.c <> nt.c) AND (sc.score > 95))
   )   
ORDER BY sc.score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do the CTEs in a single CTE.